# Pass fragments between activities

Tags: android, fragment

I want to make an application that can support portrait and landscape. The layout has two panes, on the left is the options and the right shows the result. When an option is selected the right pane shows it. But for portrait there is not enough room, so a separate activity is needed. Each option produces a different type of fragment, so I don't want to make an activity for each option when all that changes between activities is what fragment is being added there. I want to pass a fragment from the main activity to the new one, how would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to pass a fragment from the main activity to the new one, how would I do this?

You wouldn't. At most, you would follow @Ribose's answer -- pass a flag into the activity via an extra to indicate what set of fragments to create.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Moved what asker actually wants to top.

If you want to pass data to an Activity when creating it, call a version of [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)`.putExtra()` on the intent that is used in `startActivity()`. You can then use `getIntent().getStringExtra()` to (for example) get a string extra in the activity.

Say you have a piece of string data in your first activity called `myString`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME_CONSTANT, myString);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in your new activity in `onCreate` you would do:

```
String myString = this.getIntent()
        .getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME_CONSTANT, "default return value here");
```

A few notes:

- For that `EXTRA_NAME_CONSTANT`, I do mean to make a string constant of the form "your.package.name.SomeString" for example "com.example.MyString". Personally I'd even use a resource (accessed in the form `getString(R.string.extra_my_string)`) for the extra's name. They recommend you prefix it with your package name.
- You can put and get many types of data from strings to arrays to even serializable data.

---

Instead of making a separete activity for different layout orientations consider [using resource qualifiers to provide alternative layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

To summarize, make two layouts in a structure like so:

```
/res/layout/yourlayout.xml
/res/layout-land/yourlayout.xml
```

Where both XML files are named the same. Then make your default portrait layout in one and a landscape version in the other.

When you inflate the layout in `onCreate` (and when it does so automatically on a layout change during runtime) it will select the correct layout for you.

Comment: I'm not trying to make separate activity for different layout orientations, but if you have two panes and they both can't fit, you need a new activity for that second pane. I want to pass fragments from one activity to another. Each option produces a layout with check boxes and edit texts, so no two options share the same layout.

Comment: Oh very well. By the vague word "fragments" I'm still assuming you mean  any kind of data you want. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Fragments can't use this method to be placed in Extra's, and when I mean fragments, I mean: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Oh you mean Fragment the class! Well I guess I never delved into such specifics of layout. Disregard my responses, as I obviously can't help you, sorry. :( (Just as an aside, if you had capitalized Fragment I might have noticed you might be referring to some class and not responded... I just figured you were being vague. also the tag "fragment" just says "vague term" so that didn't clue me either.) Again, really sorry for wasting your time.